# SQL Subquerys and RANK()

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using below for a tournament system. The table contains registrered lengths for all teams. The result will be a scoreboard, summing up all teams length in a totalScore.

I'm trying to get the RANK() function into my SQL but I'm stuck right now. I want to get the current teams rank score out from my DB. Anyone got any ideas? I'm using MariaDB.

```
    select team, sum(length) as totalScore
from
   (SELECT t.*,
       @num_in_group:=case when @team!=team then @num_in_group:=0 else @num_in_group:=@num_in_group+1 end as num_in_group,
       @team:=team as t
    FROM reg_catches t, (select @team:=-1, @num_in_group:=0) init
    ORDER BY team asc, length desc) sub
WHERE sub.num_in_group<=4
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;
```

Table

```
team length
-----------
26   70
25   70
25   95
25   98
25   100
25   100
25   100
25   122
```

Current output

```
team    totalScore
--      --
25      520
26      70
```

Wanted output

```
rank    team    totalScore
--      --      --
1       25      520
2       26      70
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  Why do you have multiple rows?  Why are teams repeated?  What is the rank based on?

Comment: MariaDB supports `RANK()` doesn't it?  Why are you trying to hack a pretend version of it?  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/

Comment: I'm not trying to hack a version of it. My intention was to use the RANK() function but I'm failing to implement it in above questions.

Comment: I tried to update the description above to explain more what the purpose is :)

Comment: Also `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: Are you asking us to show you how to use `RANK()`?  You code seems to be trying to _simulate_ it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @row = 0;
SELECT @row:=@row + 1 rank, a.team, a.total_score 
FROM(SELECT team, sum(r.length) as total_score FROM reg_catches r GROUP BY 
r.team) a;
```

Try the above

Answer (score 0):

Got this far now with above help from Dickson, problem now is that it seems that the rank is based on team ID instead of totalScore :O

```
SET @row = 0;
SELECT @row:=@row + 1 rank, team, sum(length) as totalScore
from
   (SELECT t.*,
       @num_in_group:=case when @team!=team then @num_in_group:=0 else @num_in_group:=@num_in_group+1 end as num_in_group,
       @team:=team as t
    FROM reg_catches t, (select @team:=-1, @num_in_group:=0) init
    ORDER BY team asc, length desc) sub
WHERE sub.num_in_group<=4 and competition = "#COMPID" and disqualified = 0
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

Current output

```
rank    team    totalScore
1   28381   479
58  28468   439
20  28412   436
25  28419   432
14  28404   427
5   28388   421
```

Wanted would be

```
rank    team    totalScore
1   28381   479
2   28468   439
3   28412   436
4   28419   432
5   28404   427
6   28388   421
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/107d98/2/1